# how post form on polymer shop

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, polymer

in this starter kit -

> https://github.com/Polymer/shop/

in this file - send form, how i can post on my php script, which send email . throught polymer i not understand. help please.

> https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-checkout.html

```js
    _submit(e) {
            if (this._validateForm()) {
              // To send the form data to the server:
              // 2) Remove the code below.
              // 3) Uncomment `this.$.checkoutForm.submit()`.
              this.$.checkoutForm.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('iron-form-presubmit', {
                composed: true}));
              this._submitFormDebouncer = Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(this._submitFormDebouncer,
                Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(1000), () => {
                  this.$.checkoutForm.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('iron-form-response', {
                    composed: true, detail: {
                      response: {
                        success: 1,
                        successMessage: 'Demo checkout process complete.'
                      }
                    }}));
                });
              // this.$.checkoutForm.submit();
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<iron-form id="checkoutForm" 
           on-iron-form-response="_didReceiveResponse"
           on-iron-form-presubmit="_willSendRequest">
    <form method="post" 
          action="data/sample_success_response.json" 
          enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

You must have noticed the above line of code in the [link](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-checkout.html) you provided.
After the submit button is clicked, it will do the following steps:

1. Check validation calling the function `_validateForm()`.
2. Dispatch `iron-form-presubmit` of `checkoutForm` which will call the function `_willSendRequest`. See the attribute : `on-iron-form-presubmit="_willSendRequest"`.
3. Similarly, it will dispatch `iron-form-response` that will call `_didReceiveResponse`.
4. Then to submit the form, finally, uncomment the line `// this.$.checkoutForm.submit();`

You can change the action url to your php filename.